# Get method body c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, fxcop

I am trying to write a custom rule (code analysis) where, if the body of a method contains empty statements, an error is raised.

However, there is one problem. I can not seem to figure out how to get the body of a method (the text that is in the method).

How can I get the text inside a method, and assign it to a string?

Thanks in advance.

For reference; I use c# in visual studio, with FxCop to make the rule.

Edit: Some code added for reference, this does NOT work.

```
using Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeAnalysis.Extensibility;


public override ProblemCollection Check(Member member)
        {
            Method method = member as Method;
            if (method == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (method.Name.Name.Contains("{}"))
            {
                var resolution = GetResolution(member.Name.Name);
                var problem = new Problem(resolution, method)
                                  {
                                      Certainty = 100,
                                      FixCategory = FixCategories.Breaking,
                                      MessageLevel = MessageLevel.Warning
                                  };
                Problems.Add(problem);
            }

            return Problems;
        }
```

Comment: Have you attempted to find the solution yourself? Could you possibly show the code you used as some context?

Comment: There you go. As you can see I have tried the Contains function to compare; but if I could get the text inside a string and then compare would also be terrific. Whatever solution works.

Comment: Can you directly cast `member` to `method` like that? Not knowing the class, I would assume `method.Name.Name.ToString().Contains("{}")` might help out.

Comment: @NewAmbition Well, if you would know the basics of fxcop you would know that it works on the basic of compiled bytecode. The string representation of the bytecode will not magically get back to a readable source.

Comment: @TomTom no one mentioned magic or illusions, it was a comment purely because I commented, not to try give a magic solution. I'm sorry if I abstractly offended you by mentioning something (as an idea), but your attitude toward updating me on `fxcop` isn't one of high regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FxCop doesn't analyse source code, it works on .Net assemblies built from any language.

You may be able to find whether the method contains a statement or not using FxCop, I advice you to read the documentation and check the implementation of existing rules to understand it.

An empty statement in the middle of other code might be removed by the compiler and you may not find it using FxCop. If you want to analyze source code you should take a look at StyleCop.

Answer (score 1):

> However, there is one problem. I can not seem to figure out how to get the body of a method 
>   (the text that is in the method).

You can not. FxCop does not work based on the source, but analysis the compiled bytecode.

What you can do is find the source - which is not totally trivial - but you have to do so without the FxCop API. A start point may be analysing the pdb files (not sure where to find documentation) as they can point you to the file that contains the method.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve what I want? Being to make a rule which compares the text with the text I supplied: {}  ?

Comment: No. Again: FxCop does not work with source but with bytecode. It is called AFTER compilation on the resulting assembly. As such, the runtime has no easy access to the source and it was never planned to ahve - this is why FxCope is langauge neutral. It simply does not check the source.